# Which is a more performant schema for maintaining item position in multiple lists in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have two collections, `lists` and `items` and each item is meant to belong to any number of lists and have a custom position per list. To avoid over-architecting, which would be more performant and why?

**A: Maintaining an array of lists and their positions inside each item document itself like below:**

```js
/* item schema */
{
  _id: ObjectID, // itemID
  lists: [
    {
      _id: ObjectID, // the listID
      orderNr: Number, // the position in that specific list
    }
  ]
}
```

**B: Maintaining an extra collection `contexts` that would store an array of itemIDs in the order they're meant to appear in any given list:**

```js
/* context schema */
{
    _id: ObjectID,
    listID: ObjectID,
    items: [
        {
            _id: ObjectID, // itemID
            orderNr: Number // position of item in the list
        }
    ]
}
```

My personal understanding is that B is the better choice, as you could just query the list's context document by its `_id` field, grab a number of IDs from the start of the items array and simply query those items directly via their `_id` fields.

Whereas in version A, if I imagine there to be 5,000 items each existing in 3-4 different lists and each item having changed its position, it seems like a lot of work for Mongo to find all those items based on a value inside an array inside each item (I understand Mongo would need to search and compare all items versus just querying a limited number of items by `_id`, able to stop the moment the last _id item is found).

But perhaps there's something I don't know about MongoDB's internal workings that don't make option A a problem? It would certainly mean vastly less maintenance. Or perhaps there is a third way I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 1):

i think, option A is the better choice for schema context.

but both will require to use query `aggregation` as well even though there will an extra collection. The thing is, we need to improve the performance,

below is some of the steps to produce,

- when using `$lookup`, use Indexes like `ObjectId` to join the collections, ref: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#std-label-aggregation-pipeline-optimization-indexes-and-filters
- filter the output of the `$lookup` operation, use `pipeline` inside
- use pagination methods, so we dont have to worry if we have alot of data

there are alot of tools to generate pagination data, i suggest to use tools that using mongodb native drive

here an example tool to generate pagination where its only need once query to generate pagination data, and able perform multiple join (lookup)

[mongodb-pagination](https://github.com/mrbontor/mongo-pagination)